# Div will not expand correctly with content?

Tags: html, css, po

I have my body div within the body of my page set to body_content. I have my min-height set to 100%. Within this div, I have the main_content div which acts as a wrapper for the content. Also set to min-height of 100%. However, regardless of how I change my css, a scroll bar is added both horizontally and vertically to my body_content div. I have removed the x using hidden but I need to get rid of the y scroll bar and have the content expand correctly instead.

Mind you, right_body_menu is place to the right of main_content.

Additionally, disregard middle_body_content as I am only adding into it to test the div expansion.

```
#body_content{
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
min_height = 100%;
width = 85%;
background_color = white;
border_left = 1px solid #cacaca;
border_right = 1px solid #cacaca;
overflow-x:hidden;
padding-bottom:50px;
}

#main_content{
width: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
width: -o-calc(100% - 300px);
width: calc(100% - 300px);
height:100%;
float:left;
}

#right_body_menu{
min-height:100%;
background-color:white;
width:300px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
}


$main_content = "
<div id='main_content'>
<div id='body_top_wrapper'>
</div>
<hr>
" . $middle_body_content . "
</div>

$body_content = "
<div id='body_content'>
" . $main_content . "
</div>
```

$body_content is our var that is being echoed into the body section of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using flexbox? give the parent container and display of flex and it will grow and shrink according to the content

Comment: `#body_content{ padding-bottom:50px; }`  - this with a min height of 100% will introduce a vertical scrollbar - unless you use something like flexbox CSS

Comment: even once removed, the bar is still added. With the content I currently have inside, it would expand well pass 50px anyways.

Comment: Is that a typo in `min-height` of your `#body-content`?

Comment: I had it all in php so I misstyped while putting it into proper css for here. It is spelled correctly on my pages.

Comment: add `top: 0;` to `#right-body-menu`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is choosing to throw it away and go another direction (see OP's "answer" below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen boxes expand after eliminating height limitations. Max-width is useful, but what if you get rid of min-height?

Comment: the issues remains even after